# Compare two lists of dictionaries based on some values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list of dictionaries as:

```
old_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-20'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'},
            {'company': 'Google', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]

new_data = [{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
            {'company': 'Facebook', 'logged_in': '2019-04-12'},
            {'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

I want to filter new_data as:

1. if the company name matches in old_data and new_data select company only if logged_in time in new_data is later than in old_data
2. If company name doesnot match then select that element

expected outcome:

```
[{'company': 'Amazon', 'logged_in': '2019-01-26'},
{'company': 'LinkedIn', 'logged_in': '2019-04-20'}]
```

Comment: Cool.  What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filter_new_data = []
for old_dict, new_dict in zip(old_data, new_data):
    if new_dict['company'] not in [d['company'] for d in old_data]:
        filter_new_data.append(new_dict)
    elif new_dict['company'] == old_dict['company'] and new_dict['logged_in'] > old_dict['logged_in']:
        filter_new_data.append(new_dict)
```